# how to find places automatically after open google map - Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, google-nearby

after opening activity I want to return nearby places like for example - restaurants. Added current user location:

```
public class MainActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {
SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
FusedLocationProviderClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstaceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);

    client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        getCurrentLocation();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 44);
    }
}

private void getCurrentLocation() {
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    Task<Location> task = client.getLastLocation();
    task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
                        LatLng lating = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                        location.getLongitude());

                        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(lating)
                                .title("Current location");

                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lating, 10));
                        googleMap.addMarker(options);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

@SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == 44) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            getCurrentLocation();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Is there any way to add that auto searching?
I found something like that in documentation:

```
// Search for restaurants nearby
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=restaurants");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

It looks like solution of my problem but to be honest i don't know how to add it to my code

Comment: `tbh idk` please don't be lazy when typing your question, english isn't a first language for everyone, people might not know what this means. if there's something people don't understand, you probably won't get an answer either

Comment: the code you've posted seems pretty close if i had to guess, i'm assuming you'd need to replace `geo:0,0?` with actual lat long values though, so first get location, then start this intent perhaps ?